# Datatables : how to add chart div in child row -

Tags: charts, highcharts, datatables

how to add chart div in datatables child row ?

my code no work

I'm not programmer :(

demo code

> https:// codepen.io/intprotest/pen/QXPmBr

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blRLN.jpg)

Thanks !

code

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        responsive: true        
    });
});
 
  
Highcharts.chart('chart1', {
  
    data: {
        googleSpreadsheetKey: '1KKJgBPhFQzNzvgGHz7ygwuTJl5mXlxh1GTxOYxfyVqg'
    }
  

}); 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
 
 
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th >geo </th>
        <th> ge</th>
       
        <th class="none">... </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>HighCharts Code </td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td> 1</td>
        <td>2 </td>
        <td>  
   <div id="chart1" style="width: 300px; height: 140px;"></div>
     
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Please limit your post to a specific question and include all the relevant information (not a codepen link). Also, *my code no work* is not a problem description.

Comment: hello @TobiasTengler  ,  I want add chart div in child row and i have exemple code in codepen https://codepen.io/intprotest/pen/QXPmBr

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the data table you are using. It seems that when the row is expanded than the content of the last  element is copied to the newly created element. Unfortunately, it will not work with Highcharts.

When you change the css option and display the last column (container for Highcharts) you will see that the chart is working fine. And in the new `child`  element there is only a copy of the "real" chart. So the problem is used data table and the way it's working.

[image]